# Op Amp output's noise changes when the gain changes

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain

[image: Schematic]

I use Arduino DUE to generate a 100 Hz pulse.

I wanted to remove the DC value so I added a high pass filter and this is connected to the Op Amp([ADA4000-1](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4000-1_4000-2_4000-4.pdf))'s input. A RIGOL's DP832 power supply is giving +/- 9V to the Op Amp.

These are connected to the breadboard and I noticed when I change R2's value.

The following screenshots are the Op Amp's output.

1. R2 = 0 (Unity gain)

[image: low0]
[image: low1]

Some noise is discovered from the signal's positive peak.

2. R2 = 40k, gain = 5

[image: high0]
[image: high1]

When the gain becomes bigger, reversely, the signal's negative peak shows noise and the flat line after the positive peak seems noisy.

- What seems to be the reason for the noise when the gain changes?
- Also, what could be the solution to remove these noises?

**EDITED: You guys are right; the output was unstable due to the missing decoupling caps.**

[image: circuitBefore]
I changed it to a unity gain buffer.

Before adding the decoupling capacitor to the negative terminal,
[image: Pulse]

the same phenomenon was shown.

[image: circuitAfter]
As you see my pen pointing, adding 100nF cap,
[image: pulse after]
now it is giving a stable output! Thanks!

Two more things;

- When I touch the Op Amp's output with my finger, I discovered that the output becomes stable (by looking at the oscilloscope) without the decoupling capacitor. Why did this happen?
- This happened due to the unpopulated decoupling capacitor. Is there a name/technical jargon of this phenomenon?

Comment: How is this physically constructed (breadboard? 2-layer PCB? or what)? How long are the wires from the power supply to the op-amp board? Is there any load on the output other than the scope probe? And what are your scope's probe's capacitance?

Comment: FWIW, that looks to me more like an unstable output than noise.

Comment: You are getting noise from a high performance op-amp. The reasons would be local power decoupling at the op-amp Vcc and Vee pins and general board layout. You *cannot* use a breadboard or sloppy layout with a high performance op-amp. It will tend to ring and oscillate, or distort rising and falling edges. Just a thought...

Comment: @Sparky256 I beg to differ about using a breadboard.  The op-amp that David is using only has a GBW product of 5MHz.  With careful layout of the breadboard, that should work fine.  I've certainly built dozens, if not hundreds, of circuits on breadboards with similar and faster op-amps with no trouble (but with short wires and decoupling caps).

Comment: Please either take a picture of your breadboard and post it, or add 100nF decoupling caps from each power rail to ground and report back.  Keep your wires *short* -- putting big loops of wire right next to each other on a circuit with a high-gain part in it is like getting on your knees and begging the Oscillation Gods to give you trouble.

Comment: Hi, all. I used a breadboard with adaptor boards to mount SOIC chips. I have to admit that I have used long jumpers (50~70mm long) and I didn't add the decoupling caps from each power rail to ground. I will try it again! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oscillation is a result of instability in the layout, perhaps inductive power or ground leads without decoupling ’s on power to gnd .

Unity gain gives the widest BW (from fixed GBW) but also the lowest phase margin which degrades with any capacitive load, unless compensated with reduced BW.

There is also a slope on the pulses, which suggests another reactive effect in your layout not shown on your schematic but could be uncalibrated 10:1 probe error.

So correct that with the probe trimmer and scope test pulse , add ceramic caps. to both supply rails and use a very short probe ground lead to get textbook waveforms from DAC then OpAmp.

Even Alkaline batteries make random noise which you can hear with 1.5V on a speaker, spurious effects depend on the phase margin which can improve with gain or in your case be asymmetric while improving.

Define your capacitive load! Is there a long cable output and measure your 9V supplies with a divider.

Comment: There is also (on a breadboard in particular) a sneaky pole at the inverting input due to parasitics. A small cap across R2 might also help.

Comment: A few puff  can make a difference on 20MHz ringing near null phase margin. This can be verified with a light touch across an R or on inputs or outputs to see the effects while touching gnd.